# End to end tests WCF/.Net 4

Tags: wcf, testing

I'm looking for some best practices how to do end to end tests of a "SOA component" via WCF service.

I just started helping a group of .Net developer to set up integration tests to test their services.
The whole system is splited in 3 sub-systems, each of them have about 8 components.

My goal is to test the services of one subsystem by starting the services (self hosted or IIS hosted, both variants exist) and do an end to end test.

They actual write the unit tests with MSTest.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using some tool which is designed to test web services? For example [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/). Its way of testing services is much less complicated than creating real .NET clients in MSTest. Using such tools has another advantage - tests can be created by testers (you don't need developers for that).

As you mentioned you are doing integration testing but you are using unit testing framework for that.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is nice tool [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and couple plug ins for it.